# Best place to live for news (spikes) trading?

Tags: trading, foreign-exchange, broker, security, news

What's the best place to live for news trading? Is it US because of the best news providers and most regulated brokers?

Can I still trade 'spikes' even though I live somewhere else i.e. Australia - and the news will come some milliseconds later?

Or simply, what are the requirements to trade 'spikes'?

Thanks

Comment: Sad how many frustrated people etc. here down voting for no reasons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really depends on how you are trading the news.  These days, if you are trying to be faster than everyone you will need a trading computer co-located with the exchange you are trading on running highly optimized code and using specialized news feeds to be fastest.  Renting these computers and feeds can be very expensive but it doesn't matter where you personally are located.

On the other extreme, if you have the ability to do better analysis than other people then it doesn't necessarily matter where you are either.  Many people still make money keep track of the news do hours to days of research and then trade on overpriced or underpriced stocks.  Of course, there are people between these two extremes doing computer and/or human-based analysis that is more accurate but still pretty fast to get to the market before slower analysts.

So there are no location requirements per se.  It sounds like you are just starting out though in which case I would recommend that you find a job at a hedge fund that does the sort of strategies you are interested in.  You can learn how to best do the trading with other people's money while making a salary.  Unfortunately, there are only a few of those in Australia but firms are often willing to sponsor visas for smart people.